# How can I retrieve the namespace to a string C#

Tags: c#, string, namespaces

I am writing a program which needs the namespace of the program but I cant seem to figure out how to retrieve it. I would like the end result to be in a string.

I was able to find an MSDN page about this topic but it proved to be unhelpful to myself.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.namespace.aspx

Any help would be appreciated. The program is written in C#.

EDIT: Sorry guys, this is not a console application.

Comment: I don't understand clearly your question. Why don't you just write the namespace of your program where you want? Is it somehow changing?

Comment: @IllidanS4: This is a very valid question. Hard-coding the namespace in a string in the program is a recipe for disaster - sooner or later someone will change the namespace and forget or be unaware that it is also encoded in the program, and then it will fail.

Comment: Use case: embedded resources in an assembly have the path prefixed by the namespace. The answer below gives a strongly typed way of finding that prefix.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

This should work:

```
var myType = typeof(MyClass);
var n = myType.Namespace;
```

Write out to the console:

```
Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
Console.WriteLine("Namespace: {0}.", myType.Namespace);
```

Setting a WinForm label:

```
Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
namespaceLabel.Text = myType.Namespace;
```

Or create a method in the relevant class and use anywhere:

```
public string GetThisNamespace()
{
   return GetType().Namespace;
}
```

Comment: It's unfortunately not a console application so the significance of the {0} in the line: Console.WriteLine("   Namespace: {0}.", myType.Namespace);   is unknown to me.

Comment: Ok, what type of application is it?

Comment: The WriteLine is not the essential part her. Use `string.Format()` and move on.

Comment: It's a windows forms application.

Comment: @ElliotAmes `myType.Namespace` in this case is a string

Comment: A drawback to this approach is that moving a method to a different namespace requires you to remember to update the param passed to typeof().

Answer (score 26):

To add to all the answers.

Since C# 6.0 there is the nameof keyword.

```
string name = nameof(MyNamespace);
```

This has several advantages:

1. The name is resolved at compile-time
2. The name will change when refactoring the namespace
3. It is syntax checked, so the name must exist
4. cleaner code

**Note:** This doesn't give the full namespace though. In this case, `name` will be equal to `Bar`:

```
namespace Foo.Bar
{
   string name = nameof(Foo.Bar);
}
```

Comment: As it currently stands, this answer is misleading as it will _only_ work with single segment namespaces.

Comment: @ThePademelon, technically it does. If you want the names of the namespaces which contain the namespace you reference, maybe do something like `$"{nameof(ns1)}.{nameof(ns2)}"`

Comment: A drawback to this approach is that moving a method to a different namespace requires you to remember to update the param passed to nameof().

Answer (score 20):

Put this to your assembly:

```
public static string GetCurrentNamespace()
{
    return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EntryPoint.DeclaringType.Namespace;
}
```

Or if you want this method to be in a library used by your program, write it like this:

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static string GetCurrentNamespace()
{
    return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().EntryPoint.DeclaringType.Namespace;
}
```

Comment: This is better than the typeof() and nameof() answers because a method that uses GetCurrentNamespace() can be moved to a different class or an entirely different namespace without requiring a code change.

Answer (score 11):

This can't go wrong:

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace
```

Comment: How is this better than the accepted answer and the other variants posted here?

Comment: This line can be used verbatim in any method in an application.  The accepted answer has been written around getting the typeof(MyClass).  So for truly copy/paste friendly code this wins (though is probably a bit slower at runtime).

Answer (score 9):

You could simply use [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) and then pass in the class (I.e. Program):

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program).Namespace);
```

Which would print:

```
ConsoleApplication1
```

Answer (score 9):

if you have item `x` of class `A` in namespace `B` you can use:

```
string s = x.GetType().Namespace;
```

no `s` contains "B"

you can also use `x.GetType().Name` to get the type name or `x.GetType().FullName` to get both

Answer (score 3):

```
Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
// Get the namespace of the myClass class.
Console.WriteLine("Namespace: {0}.", myType.Namespace);
```

Building on Joe's comment you can still use

```
Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
// Get the namespace of the myClass class.
var namespaceName = myType.Namespace.ToString();
```

with `namespaceName` being a variable to access the namespace name as a string value.

Answer (score 3):

If you're executing it from a class in the namespace you need to capture then you can just use:

`GetType().Namespace`

This works nicely as it then allows you to refactor the namespace and will still work.

Answer (score 2):

as a roll upp all post answers: 
getting all columns' values from a table given as a string tableName:

```
     var tableName = "INVENTORY_PRICE";
                var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

                var tip = typeof(Form3);

                var t = assembly.GetType(tip.Namespace + "." + tableName);
                if (t != null)
                {
                    var foos = db.GetTable(t);

                    foreach (var f in foos)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(f + ":");
                        foreach (var property in f.GetType().GetProperties())
                            if (property != null)
                            {
                                var pv = property.GetValue(f, null);
                                Console.WriteLine("   " + property.Name + ":" + pv);
                            }

                        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
                    }
                }
```

it is very easy if we use ado, this sample uses LINQ context...