# How to get the full name of a namespace as a string in C#?

Tags: c#, namespaces, nameof

I'm trying to get the full name of a namespace and convert it to a string.

Specifically, I have the namespace `DevExpress.Xpf` and I would like `nameof2(DevExpress.Xpf)` or some equivalent to return `"DevExpress.Xpf"`, rather than the `"Xpf"` that `nameof` returns.

Currently, I am using `$"{nameof(DevExpress)}.{nameof(DevExpress.Xpf)}"` to achieve this end.

Is it possible to use reflection or some other feature of C# to get the full address of a namespace as a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I retrieve the namespace to a string C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485469/how-can-i-retrieve-the-namespace-to-a-string-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Namespace` property of the Type object returns the fully qualified name of the namespace the type's declared in.
So considering you have a class named `A` in the namespace `DevExpress.Xpf`, calling `typeof(A).Namespace` will return `"DevExpress.Xpf"`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on namespaces themselves, only types.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not on a on pc that can run C# but something like this should work.

string name = nameof(DevExpress.Xpf);

*(i'm assumming DevExpress.Xpf is the correct namespace name because you wrote that in the question)*

Comment: That would just return the string `"Xpf"`